# Web Server statistics script in javascript

Tags: linux, webserver, cpanel

I need a script in javascript (or c#) which cal log the statistics of a web server (cPanel based)

There is inbuild script in cPanel - Awstats. but its in PHP and perl.
That would be fine if there is any service layer available which gives PHP data in XML.

I need suggestion ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

It is not cPanel integrated but you can try Google Analytics

Comment: no i want server statistics too like server overhead, CPU ram utilization, cPanel accounts etc. so i would prefer cPanel integrated services.